# i am using animation-iteration-count property for left to right animation how can i remove or hide the div once the animation is over

Tags: css, animation, iteration, css-animations, keyframe

i am using animation-iteration-count property in css for left to right animation how can i remove or hide  the div once the animation is over at the ending point i.e, it should be removed from left to right with animation once reached 100%.
same as we see picture in gallery app 
does its have any such property.
pls i need the solution only in css.
below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation: mymove 1s;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 0;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation: mymove 1s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
from {left: 0px;}
to {left: 100%;}
}
@keyframes mymove {
from {left: 0px;}
to {left: +100%;}
background: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The animation-iteration-count property is not       supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `animation-fill-mode` css property. Use either `both` or `forwards` as a value.

> The animation-fill-mode property specifies a style for the element
>   when the animation is not playing (when it is finished, or when it has
>   a delay).

More info [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp).

---

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/oaax36mh/)**

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 1s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 0;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation: mymove 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The animation-iteration-count property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>
<div></div>
```